# Android TV RecyclerView MultiLayout focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, television

I have a Android TV program,and use a RecyclerView with MultiLayout, It have several ImageView in each item.Now how can the ImageView requestFocus using DPAD.
I'd appreciate it if anyone had the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to custom click in your recycle view item, when you need it, and it catch the focus.